# multiplication of every line

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I would like to calculate a value on every line of a file such as this:

```
1  1441792,11534336
2  1048576,8388608
3  1441792,1153433
4  1966080,15728640
5  393216,3145728
6  2621440,20971520
7  2490368,19922944
```

I need to acquire the second value (`11534336`, `8388608`, [...]) and multiply by, for example, 3, and save this value to a new file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` too

```
 awk -F "," '{print $2*3}' src.dat  > newfile
```

where
`src.dat` is your source data (input)
`newfile` the new file one   (output)
`-F ","` use as Field separator the `,`
`$2` is used to take the second field (what is after the `,`)

Answer (score 2):

Here's `dc` and `sed` doing the job:

```
#v#backref courtesy Stephane's comment#v#
sed 's/.*,\(.*\)/[&,]P\1 *3p/' <<-\DATA | dc
    1  1441792,11534336
    2  1048576,8388608
    3  1441792,1153433
    4  1966080,15728640
    5  393216,3145728
    6  2621440,20971520
    7  2490368,19922944
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1  1441792,11534336,34603008
2  1048576,8388608,25165824
3  1441792,1153433,3460299
4  1966080,15728640,47185920
5  393216,3145728,9437184
6  2621440,20971520,62914560
7  2490368,19922944,59768832
```

It's *very* fast.

You can do the same without any backreferences - if it makes any difference - in this way:

```
 sed 's/^/[/;s/[^,]*$/&,]P& 3*p/' <file | dc
```

If you don't want them all together and want only the results it's easier still:

```
sed 's/.*,//;s/$/ 3*p/' <file | dc
```

And if you want the lines numbered:

```
sed 's/.*,//;s/$/ 3*p/' <file | dc | nl
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't know if I agree that backreferences are simpler - though I did consider it. Maybe I just don't agree because I don't understand what - if any - performance impact they may have. The `n` information is very handy though - thank you. Maybe I'll switch it around and do the multiplication in a register...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - does `P` have the same constraints? Actually, I think I will use the backref after all - if you don't mind. It can't be much different than `&...&` I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's integer arithmetic, you could probably do it directly in the shell - for example in `bash`

```
while IFS="$IFS," read n x y; do printf '%d\n' "$((3*y))"; done < file > newfile
```

Testing to `stdout`

```
$ while IFS="$IFS," read n x y; do printf '%d\n' "$((3*y))"; done < file
34603008
25165824
3460299
47185920
9437184
62914560
59768832
```

Comment: If the result approaches 20 or so digits this will likely fail.